# Error in main thread: MKNormalizedPointForLayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

I am developing Core-Location based `iPhone` application and there is some strange error.

When I send app in the background state and send it back to foreground, in main thread is error named `MKNormalizedPointForLayer` and nothing more.

Where I have to go to find solution? Google is poor about it.

Comment: Please include full error message and stack trace.

Comment: I have found solution. Problem was that app was returning latitude and longitude out of the right interval (0,180), something like 800.546444. It was in my code. Thank you.

Comment: Nice. If the `MKNormalizedPointForLayer` error was caused by some kind  of out of range usage of the API I think you could answer your own question with a short description what caused it. Would probably be helpful for others searching for that error.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you fixed this as I received this error a while ago and worked around it instead of debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I have no description, but my math calculation was incorrect. For example I calculate number 4000.0 for latitude, wat is wrong. Thats all.