# Getting a periodic crash when stopping MKMapKit location services

Tags: mkmapview

I get a very infrequent crash when stopping MKMapView location services in the applicationDidEnterBackground method.  (I'm doing this to ensure that my app does not use location services when the app is in the background.)

The code which gives rise to the crash looks like this:

```
- (void)MyAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *app) {
     [self.baseAppViewController stopUserTracking];
}
```

The stopUserTracking method does the following:

```
-(void)stopUserTracking {
    [baseAppViewController.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone];
    [baseAppViewController.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
}
```

Note that the baseAppViewController is never released by the app; neither is the mapView.  The baseAppViewController is the delegate of its mapView.  The delegate is never set to nil.

Here is the stack trace, which ends with a call to MKNormalizedPointForLayer.  I've read elsewhere that the MKNormalizedPointForLayer may be due to an invalid annotation latlng (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766272/error-in-main-thread-mknormalizedpointforlayer).  However I doubt that this is the case for my app:  I've tried purposefully adding annotations with invalid lat/lngs, and don't get this error.  The fact that this is happening as a result of the MKTilesRequireGoogleLegalNotices call is intriguing, but completely puzzling.  Any thoughts?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MapKit                              0x32b5de94 MKNormalizedPointForLayer + 28043
1   MapKit                              0x32b5dd8f MKNormalizedPointForLayer + 27782
2   MapKit                              0x32b5dca3 MKNormalizedPointForLayer + 27546
3   MapKit                              0x32b6b901 MKTilesRequireGoogleLegalNotices + 44500
4   MapKit                              0x32b69eed MKTilesRequireGoogleLegalNotices + 37824
5   MapKit                              0x32b50673 MKTileSupportsTileSetStyle + 15378
6   MyApp                           0x00040061 -[BaseAppViewController stopUserTracking] (BaseAppViewController.m:785)
7   MyApp                           0x0001e3c9 -[MyAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] (MyAppDelegate.m:325)
8   UIKit                               0x334fd235 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 760
9   UIKit                               0x3348deff -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2094
10  UIKit                               0x3348d567 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 54
11  MyApp                           0x000fcb41 -[UIApplication(HMCustom) customSendEvent:] + 85
12  UIKit                               0x3348cf3b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
13  GraphicsServices                    0x3764c22b PurpleEventCallback + 882
14  CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
15  CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
16  CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
17  CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
18  CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
19  GraphicsServices                    0x3764b439 GSEventRunModal + 136
20  UIKit                               0x334bbcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
21  MyApp                           0x000026d3 main (main.m:27)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x348e9c29 _dispatch_mgr_wakeup + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   WebCore                             0x318aeca3 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 402
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   MyApp                           0x00033823 LoggerWorkerThread (LoggerClient.m:494)
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630f570 __select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   Foundation                          0x354e8bb9 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
6   Foundation                          0x354e8a81 -[NSThread main] + 72
7   Foundation                          0x3557c591 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   MapKit                              0x32b4de1d MKTileSupportsTileSetStyle + 5052
6   Foundation                          0x354e8a81 -[NSThread main] + 72
7   Foundation                          0x3557c591 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   MyApp                           0x0007e78b +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] + 171
6   Foundation                          0x354e8a81 -[NSThread main] + 72
7   Foundation                          0x3557c591 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
8   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   WebCore                             0x318d80d9 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 128
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e16cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x362ff004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2d3f3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
2   CoreFoundation                      0x35a2c12b __CFRunLoopRun + 882
3   CoreFoundation                      0x359af4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
4   CoreFoundation                      0x359af36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   Foundation                          0x354dcb75 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 256
6   MyApp                           0x0011d50d +[FlurryHTTPEater sendMethod:to:body:headerFields:timeoutInterval:useWebView:] (FlurryHTTPEater.m:67)
7   MyApp                           0x00126ae9 +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerWithTimeout:useWebView:requestAppCircleAds:requestVideoAds:requestAppSpotAds:requestReengageAds:sendCurrentSession:] (FlurrySession.m:1053)
8   MyApp                           0x001265c7 +[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerForAppCircle] (FlurrySession.m:1016)
9   Foundation                          0x354e8a81 -[NSThread main] + 72
10  Foundation                          0x3557c591 __NSThread__main__ + 1048
11  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32e1c735 _pthread_start + 320

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x3630fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000     r1: 0x00000000     r2: 0x00000000     r3: 0x41a00000 
    r4: 0x003b3520     r5: 0x003b3520     r6: 0xfffffffc     r7: 0x2fea761c 
    r8: 0x3f01fae8     r9: 0x00000000    r10: 0x0eaec170    r11: 0x3f485f10 
    ip: 0xbff00000     sp: 0x2fea7610     lr: 0x32b548ef     pc: 0x32b5de94 
  cpsr: 0x20080030 

Binary Images:
  (truncated)
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: I think we did, but never figured out the real cause.  We turned off map scroll & zoom animations, and that seems to have fixed it.  Not very satisfying, I know.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that it can be that, but your problem might come from a "delegate" problem. 
Try to call this line in your method stopUserTracking :

```
baseAppViewController.mapView.delegate = nil;
```

This should prevent the map from sending information to deallocated instance of your view controller, causing your app to crash. 
Be sure to add this line when your app is reloading from background (maybe in viewWillAppear ?) to make sure your app behaves correctly :

```
 baseAppViewController.mapView.delegate = self;
```

If it does not solve your problem, try to enable "Zombie object" in the options of your configurations as mentioned here : [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4) it oftens helps to understand what's happening when such unexpected errors happens in apps.